# Local html url in webbrowser control (visual basic)

Tags: vb.net, basic

I'm a beginner in VB, I'm trying to display html page in the webbrowser control.
when I copy the full path of the html file, and put in the url properties of the webbrowser control, everything works. However, when I build the exe file and run it in different computer, the html page can not be displayed.
I know this has to do with the html file path, I'm trying to find a way to display html page using webbrowser control in any computer.

any help will be great guys.

Comment: I tried to use:
WebBrowser1.Navigate(App.Path & "\info.htm")
but it gives me the error " 'App' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) & "\info.html")
```

remember to add

```
Imports System.IO
```

Comment: nothing happens, I tried to copy info.html to all possible folders of the application (ex bin, debug ...) but nothing happens

Comment: try building application and then copy info.html to Release folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but better late then never! Sorry I did not find this sooner!
Anyway, instead of adding the file url in the URL property of WebBrowser1, here is what you need to do:

1. In `Form1_Load` add the following code:

   `Dim appPath As String
       appPath = Application.StartupPath
       WebBrowser1.Navigate(appPath & "/html-file-name-here.html")`
2. Change the "html-file-name-here.html" to what your HTML file name is.
3. Then when you compile your app, just put your html file in the folder where the app is launching from .